# Query regarding Getting Latitude and Longitude

Tags: blackberry, cell, latitude-longitude

In Blackberry ,
Is there a cost involved when we hit the Google with a cell ID and get the corresponding Latitude and Longitudes for an application?

Comment: I did it a long time ago (1yr +), and then it was free. You run your code in simulator. If simulator can get the response, then it may be still free.

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is about API pricing / terms of use not directly programming

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Its Free as far as i know 
its just the cost of Net that gets charged